# Get specific sheet by its GID in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With this:

```
getSheetByName('test');
```

I can select a Sheet by it's name. But how can I select it by the `GID` which is at the end of the url? In my example: `"...edit#gid=1063355045"`

I already tried something like `getSheetById('1063355045');` - but this is not working.

Comment: That's probably true.  That's why I like to dabble with answers like this because you guys will catch me and I will learn something.

Comment: @Cooper I am also here for the same thing. I asked you that to learn if this could work. Thank you too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation:

As you have also noticed, there is no such a method to get a sheet object by its id.

However, you can do some `JavaScript` tricks:

- Get all the sheets of your document with [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets).
- Use [getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetId()) to get the `gid` of all the sheets.
- [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the one with the chosen `gid`.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const gid = "1063355045"; // select the gid of your choice
  const sheet = sheets.filter(sh=>sh.getSheetId()==gid)[0]; // this is the sheet object
  console.log(sheet.getSheetName());
}
```

`sheet` is the desired sheet with the particular `gid`. You can apply all the [sheet methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) to that object.

### Construct your own `getSheetByGid` function:

```
function myFunction(){
  const gid = "1063355045";
  const sheet = getSheetByGid(gid);
}

function getSheetByGid(gid){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const sheet = sheets.filter(sh=>sh.getSheetId()==gid)[0]; // this is the sheet object
  return sheet;
}
```